# Stripe subscribtion upgrade

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripes

I have 1 basic yearly subscription and 1 premium yearly subscription, when user wanted to upgrade from basic to premium, it will be free upgrade to premium for the remaining time of the basic plan, but I want to collect the premium subscription fee in advance for the next year.
so after the user completes the payment the remaining time of the premium subscription is the **remaining time of the basic plan + 1-year premium subscription**

Any idea how could I achieve this using stripe API?
here is the related document link
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update

Expecting to allow user to upgrade to a premium subscription for free in the remaining time of the basic subscription, but collect the premium subscription fee in advance for next year.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to break the timeline in 3 sections:

- (a) 1st year on basic (e.g. 1 Jan - 31 June 2022).
- (b) 1st year after upgrade to premium (e.g. 1 Jul - 31 Dec 2022).
- (c) 2nd year on premium (e.g. 1 Jan - 31 Dec 2023).

Price for (a) and (b) is basic, for (c) is premium. Service in (a) is basic, in (b) and (c) is premium. The payment for the 2nd year is done between (a) and (b), e.g. on June 31. Please, correct me if I’m wrong.

One way of doing it is to have 3 different prices:

- Basic subscription for basic price e.g. $10.
- Premium subscription for basic price e.g. $10.
- Premium subscription for premium price e.g. $30.

When the customer upgrades, you perform 3 steps one after another:

1. Create a [standalone Invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/integration/quickstart) and charge the customer once for the 1 year of Price #3, e.g. $30. You can’t charge the customer for the upcoming invoice of the new subscription, however you can add a discount in the step 3.
2. Update the existing subscription to Price #2 - the customer gets premium service for a basic price e.g. $10. Set `cancel_at_period_end: true`.
3. Create a new [subscription schedule](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules), with Price #3 - $30, and set the `start_date` after the old subscription ends. Add a one-time 100% discount to the subscription for the first year (because the customer paid for it in step 1).

I know it is a bit convoluted, as this is quite an uncommon scenario, but I managed to get it working on my end. You can use the [Stripe Test Clock](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks) to make the testing easier.

Comment: The scenario above is correct. In my case am having multiple plans in one subscription, so am considering in section b above, instead of updating the existing subscription plan from basic to premium, could I just delete the basic plan subscription and create a new premium subscription add a free trial until the remaining time of the basic plan + 1-year premium subscription plan

Comment: Yes, this would work too. You just need to make sure to set [proration_behaviour](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior) to `none` if you don't want to credit the user for the rest of the year, when you remove the basic plan.